# Golang: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: golang

У меня есть функция *http_crack()* её выполнение проходит успешно если переменная error возвратит true, а если она возвращает nil то программа прекращает свое действие с ошибкой:

```
**panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference**
*[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x38 pc=0x5d9928]*
```

Вот сам код моей программы:

```
func http_crack() {

    //full-headers example

    //  HTTP/1.x 200 OK
    //  Date: Sat, 12 Dec 2009 15:41:52 GMT
    //  Server: Apache/2.0.61 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.61 OpenSSL/0.9.8k mod_dp20/0.99.2 PHP/5.2.5 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.5.1 mod_ruby/1.2.6 Ruby/1.8.6(2007-09-24)
    //  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.5
    //  Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=ft47gokfee6amv3eda3k1p93s3; path=/
    //  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    //  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    //  Pragma: no-cache
    //  Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=1024
    //  Connection: Keep-Alive
    //  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    //  Content-Type: text/html

    response, err := http.Get(os.Args[1])
    response.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2a1pre) Gecko")
    response.Header.Set("Referer", "http://127.0.0.1/foo-bar/index.html")
    response.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; param=value")

    t_time := time.Now()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Hello")
    } else {
        if response.StatusCode == 200 {
            fmt.Println(t_time.Format(time.RFC3339), "OK")
        } else {
            fmt.Println(t_time.Format(time.RFC3339), "BAD")
        }
    }



}
```

Я чу-чуть догадываюсь что нужно поставить defer на одну из переменных куда-то под get методы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func http_crack(url string) {


if response, err := http.Get(url); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf(err.Error())
} else {
    fmt.Printf("Responce: %v   Error: %v\n", response, err)
    response.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2a1pre) Gecko")
    response.Header.Set("Referer", "http://127.0.0.1/foo-bar/index.html")
    response.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; param=value")

    t_time := time.Now()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Hello")
    } else {
        if response.StatusCode == 200 {
            fmt.Println(t_time.Format(time.RFC3339), "OK")
        } else {
            fmt.Println(t_time.Format(time.RFC3339), "BAD")
        }
    }

}
```

}

В Go принято сразу обрабатывать ошибку, при условии ее возникновения. Это значительно облегчает понимание и чтение кода другим лицам, в довесок к этому так [рекомендуют сами разработчики](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html).
А ошибка у тебя была в том, что компилятор при ошибке  пытался использовать объект response а он "пустой", то есть компилятор "ожидал" найти по указателю на адрес памяти объект response а по факту там ничего не было в связи с ошибкой вызова метода .get.